# Copy multiple cell colours from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice when it comes to building VBA code. I want to automatically copy cell colours from one worksheet to another.

I have provided some images below to help explain what I am hoping to achieve:

Worksheet 1 - Mar 18:
[image: Worksheet 1 - Mar 18]

Worksheet 7 - Site 1:
[image: Worksheet 7 - Site 1]

Looking at Worksheet 1 - Mar 18, I want to copy the cell colours from row 3 (B3 to X3) to Worksheet 7 - site 1 Column B (B3 to B23). I also have additional worksheets, Apr 18 to Dec 18 and Site 2 to Site 6 where I would like to perform similar actions.

The end result will roll up the information from the month worksheets into the site worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple routine that demonstrates how cells on one sheet can be colored based on the color of cells in a second sheet. After you thoroughly understand how this code works, you should be able to modify it to apply to your situation.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
Sub colorCells()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, numToColor As Integer, i As Integer
Set sh1 = Worksheets("1")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("2")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("B3")
Set r2 = sh2.Range("B3")
numToColor = 10
For i = 1 To numToColor
  r2.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = r1.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Sub CopyColors

    Worksheets("Mar 18").Range("B3:X3").Copy
    Worksheets("site 1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

 End Sub
```

And extend to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub CopyColor()
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim cell As Range
'loop through all cells in specified range in specified worksheet
For Each cell In Worksheets("Mar 18").Range("B3:X3")
    ' copy color and paste it to another cells in worksheet Site 1
    Worksheets("Site 1").Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = cell.Interior.Color
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```